# Alternative ways to shutdown ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: shutdown

I am new to ubuntu and I already have some problems with it, whenever I try to shutdown my screen freezes forever and I have to hold power bottom to turn off my laptop.

I know there were similar questions but fixes that were posted didn't solve my problem except one, writing `sudo swapoff -a && systemctl poweroff` in terminal.

But what bothers me is that I don't know whether it is safe to shut down my laptop in this way, I would be grateful to know some other ways to shutdown that won't damage my hardware.

Comment: What is you laptop make/model ? Did you upgrade to 16.04.04? Does the screen freeze instantly or after displaying something else?

Comment: It's not entirely clear why you'd assume a forced shutdown should "damage my hardware". In fact, holding the power button is an alternative.

Comment: Two answer at least the question that concerns you most: yes, the code snippet you show is a safe way to shutdown. But you (or we) should figure out, why you cannot shutdown the usual way.

Comment: @mikewhatever Pressing the power button for 5 seconds (as I understand the question) is NOT safe. It's like unplugging the power cord.

Comment: When you shutdown "normally" and the purple Ubuntu screen appears, can you press ESC to toggle between the purple screen and the shutdown protocol (a bunch of text messages)? These messages might narrow down the error.

Comment: @RobAu  my laptop is Asus - X556UQ, it freezes instantly and nothing is shown on the screen, I read that pressing ESC when it freezes should show me something but it doesn't

Comment: @PerlDuck Thank you for answer! now that I know it is safe to use I will be using it till I find the solution

Answer (score 1):

You can shut down  your laptop with command line.
Use this command

```
$ sudo init 0
```

Comment: This is just another way to say `systemctl poweroff`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to investigate what is blocking the shutdown process.

Do

CTRL+ALT+F2

Then

CTRL+ALT+DEL

Followed by ESC to display shutdown steps. You should now be able to see what's wrong and post it here as comment.